# JBoss (EAP 7.0) equivalent classes for Weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, jboss-eap-7, server-migration

I have been trying to migrate from Weblogic to JBoss EAP 7.0. The problem being faced is in code deployment as JBoss does not support anything related to Weblogic specific classes and Java RPC.
The code base uses some of the Weblogic specific classes for which I am not able to find JBoss equivalent classes.
Classes are below for which I require JBoss equivalent classes:

1. weblogic.wsee.connection.transport.http.HttpTransportInfo
2. weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl

I was trying to re-write the class which uses the above two classes but when I decompiled "HttpTransportInfo", I found out that it uses a number of other weblogic imports and same was the case for ServiceImpl.java.

So if anyone could suggest the alternate for above two mentioned classes in JBoss that would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: I already went through https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebLogic+to+AS+7, but it does not talk about how to migrate the weblogic specific classes to JBoss.

Comment: This gives a "hint" on your first missing class [Red_Hat_JBoss_Migration_Toolkit-2.6 Windup Rules Development Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Migration_Toolkit/2.6/pdf/Windup_Rules_Development_Guide/Red_Hat_JBoss_Migration_Toolkit-2.6-Windup_Rules_Development_Guide-en-US.pdf)

Comment: And a better resource which might help with both, it does include the second [weblogic webservices windup](https://github.com/windup/windup-rulesets/blob/master/rules-reviewed/eap6/weblogic/weblogic-webservices.windup.xml) in short, just sounds like you need to use plain old JAX-WS rather than anything weblogic related unless you want to include the particular jars you missing which basically defeats moving to JBoss ;-) Now lesson learned e.g. dont use app server specific classes for easier portability (though I too am guilty at times)

Comment: Red Hat provides a migration toolkit (web-based / CLI based /Eclipse plugin) which can be used to migrate your application from WebLogic to EAP easily. It will generate a complete report of what changes needs to be done to migrate your application from WebLogic to EAP.

Comment: How did you resolve the problem?