# Configure programmatically a proxy server when invoking a web service using soap and jax-rpc

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, proxy

I would like to programmatically configure a proxy server when invoking a web service using soap and jax-rpc from java/spring boot application.
I know this can be done through system properties

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
```

but is there a way to configure it only for one service/client call rather than for the whole application? I found this example based on Oracle [weblogic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13760/client.htm#WSRPC215) but I am using java app with spring boot/tomcat and jboss/jaxrpc libraries and cannot use HttpTransportInfo.
Also found someone looking for Jboss implementation of it [HttpTransportInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950646/jboss-eap-7-0-equivalent-classes-for-weblogic)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447127/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-for-a-jax-ws-request-without-setting-a-system-wide-p

Comment: Many Thanks @AlexChernyshev, using custom ProxySelector is the way to go!